# Can custom tools be integrated with TortoiseSVN UI?

Tags: tortoisesvn

Is it possible to add custom tools to the TortoiseSVN menus?  I'm looking to attach custom command-line tools or scripts (eg for our code-review system) such that they could be invoked against a filename, or repository URL, or against a revision number.

I've used other SCM tools (eg p4client) where you could set a command-template on either a path element (eg file/directory), or on a changeset (eg in the log viewer, or a pending changeset).  The tool would simply substitute some special patterns with the path,  changelist, or whatever as appropriate and blindly call the tool.

I'm not talking about commit/update hooks, its really about being able to browse the SVN history, select a change and fire off a tool-command.

Comment: It seems to me you could find this information by checking the [TortoiseSVN documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/).

Comment: I can't see anything about hooking up custom commands.  I _can_ see a reference to a code-review tool (which doesn't seem to exist on my version), but not generic hooks from which to fire off external tools.  Which chapter are you looking in?

Comment: I also see you can replace the diff/merge tools, but again that's not what I'm asking for,  I'm happy with the diff/merge tools from Tortoise.